# I would like to make a panel to manage reviews

Tags: javascript, php, html, mysql, database

I made a website where I have a page for reviews, where users can freely write, but I would like the requests to arrive in a panel before they are published where I can reject or approve the reviews. How should I do?

I would simply like to make sure that not all posts are approved.

CODE:

```
function time_elapsed_string($datetime, $full = false) {
    $now = new DateTime;
    $ago = new DateTime($datetime);
    $diff = $now->diff($ago);
    $diff->w = floor($diff->d / 7);
    $diff->d -= $diff->w * 7;
    $string = array('y' => 'year', 'm' => 'month', 'w' => 'week', 'd' => 'day', 'h' => 'hour', 'i' => 'minute', 's' => 'second');
    foreach ($string as $k => &$v) {
        if ($diff->$k) {
            $v = $diff->$k . ' ' . $v . ($diff->$k > 1 ? 's' : '');
        } else {
            unset($string[$k]);
        }
    }
    if (!$full) $string = array_slice($string, 0, 1);
    return $string ? implode(', ', $string) . ' ago' : 'just now';
}

if (isset($_GET['page_id'])) {
    
    if (isset($_POST['name'], $_POST['rating'], $_POST['content'])) {

        $stmt = $pdo->prepare('INSERT INTO reviews 
                            (page_id, name, content, rating, submit_date) 
                        VALUES (?,?,?,?,NOW())');
        $stmt->execute([$_GET['page_id'], $_POST['name'],
                        $_POST['content'], $_POST['rating']]);
        exit('Your review has been submitted!');
    }

    $stmt = $pdo->prepare('SELECT * FROM reviews WHERE page_id = ? ORDER BY submit_date DESC');
    $stmt->execute([$_GET['page_id']]);
    $reviews = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

    $stmt = $pdo->prepare('SELECT AVG(rating) AS overall_rating, COUNT(*) AS total_reviews FROM reviews WHERE page_id = ?');
    $stmt->execute([$_GET['page_id']]);
    $reviews_info = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
} else {
    exit('Please provide the page ID.');
}
?>
<div class="overall_rating">
    <span class="num"><?=number_format($reviews_info['overall_rating'], 1)?></span>
    <span class="stars"><?=str_repeat('&#9733;', round($reviews_info['overall_rating']))?></span>
    <span class="total"><?=$reviews_info['total_reviews']?> reviews</span>
</div>
<a href="#" class="write_review_btn">Write Review</a>
<div class="write_review">
    <form>
        <input name="name" type="text" placeholder="Your Name" required>
        <input name="rating" type="number" min="1" max="5" placeholder="Rating (1-5)" required>
        <textarea name="content" placeholder="Write your review here..." required></textarea>
        <button type="submit">Submit Review</button>
    </form>
</div>
<?php foreach ($reviews as $review): ?>
<div class="review">
    <h3 class="name"><?=htmlspecialchars($review['name'], ENT_QUOTES)?></h3>
    <div>
        <span class="rating"><?=str_repeat('&#9733;', $review['rating'])?></span>
        <span class="date"><?=time_elapsed_string($review['submit_date'])?></span>
    </div>
    <p class="content"><?=htmlspecialchars($review['content'], ENT_QUOTES)?></p>
</div>
<?php endforeach ?>
```

Comment: Add an `active` column to posts. The creator code sets it to Inactibe (0) Your admin code selects `where active = 0` and set `active = 1` when you say it can go live

Comment: Thank you!I solved

Answer (score 1):

I would like to elaborate on the answer by [@RiggsFolly](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2310830/riggsfolly)

### Intro

So first of all like the comment advised you could create an active field which would be 0 or 1 so that can be a bool/tinyint/etc. However, I would recommend 3 states, 0 - Pending Review, 1 - Active, 2 - Rejected. The reason for this is that in your admin panel you want the ones you reject to disappear. So in your admin panel, you can just select all with the active status of 0 and maybe have another page or filter to select ones that were approved/rejected. Don't wanna review the same posts over and over again.

### Example

I prefer using ENUMs just because it feels more descriptive, but feel free to use anything else even numbers 0 1 2. For my example, I would first alter the table structure and create a new column called `status` of type `ENUM` with possible values `awaiting`, `accepted`, `rejected`.

#### Submitting Posts

When you are submitting posts you want it to default to the awaiting state, if you set this as the default in MySQL and not null no additional change is needed really. However, you should probably change the SQL entering the post as follows:

```
INSERT INTO reviews (page_id, name, content, rating, submit_date, status) VALUES (?,?,?,?,NOW(), "awaiting")
```

#### Retrieving Posts

When you retrieve posts, you only want to retrieve approved posts so you should adapt your SQL to this:

```
SELECT * FROM reviews WHERE page_id = ? AND status = "accepted" ORDER BY submit_date DESC
```

#### Retrieving Average

Similarly, you only want to average published posts.

```
SELECT AVG(rating) AS overall_rating, COUNT(*) AS total_reviews FROM reviews WHERE page_id = ? AND status = "accepted"
```

### Final Code

```
function time_elapsed_string($datetime, $full = false) {
    $now = new DateTime;
    $ago = new DateTime($datetime);
    $diff = $now->diff($ago);
    $diff->w = floor($diff->d / 7);
    $diff->d -= $diff->w * 7;
    $string = array('y' => 'year', 'm' => 'month', 'w' => 'week', 'd' => 'day', 'h' => 'hour', 'i' => 'minute', 's' => 'second');
    foreach ($string as $k => &$v) {
        if ($diff->$k) {
            $v = $diff->$k . ' ' . $v . ($diff->$k > 1 ? 's' : '');
        } else {
            unset($string[$k]);
        }
    }
    if (!$full) $string = array_slice($string, 0, 1);
    return $string ? implode(', ', $string) . ' ago' : 'just now';
}

if (isset($_GET['page_id'])) {
    
    if (isset($_POST['name'], $_POST['rating'], $_POST['content'])) {

        $stmt = $pdo->prepare('INSERT INTO reviews 
                            (page_id, name, content, rating, submit_date, status) 
                        VALUES (?,?,?,?,NOW(), "awaiting")');
        $stmt->execute([$_GET['page_id'], $_POST['name'],
                        $_POST['content'], $_POST['rating']]);
        exit('Your review has been submitted!');
    }

    $stmt = $pdo->prepare('SELECT * FROM reviews WHERE page_id = ? AND status = "accepted" ORDER BY submit_date DESC');
    $stmt->execute([$_GET['page_id']]);
    $reviews = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

    $stmt = $pdo->prepare('SELECT AVG(rating) AS overall_rating, COUNT(*) AS total_reviews FROM reviews WHERE page_id = ? AND status = "accepted"');
    $stmt->execute([$_GET['page_id']]);
    $reviews_info = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
} else {
    exit('Please provide the page ID.');
}
?>
<div class="overall_rating">
    <span class="num"><?=number_format($reviews_info['overall_rating'], 1)?></span>
    <span class="stars"><?=str_repeat('&#9733;', round($reviews_info['overall_rating']))?></span>
    <span class="total"><?=$reviews_info['total_reviews']?> reviews</span>
</div>
<a href="#" class="write_review_btn">Write Review</a>
<div class="write_review">
    <form>
        <input name="name" type="text" placeholder="Your Name" required>
        <input name="rating" type="number" min="1" max="5" placeholder="Rating (1-5)" required>
        <textarea name="content" placeholder="Write your review here..." required></textarea>
        <button type="submit">Submit Review</button>
    </form>
</div>
<?php foreach ($reviews as $review): ?>
<div class="review">
    <h3 class="name"><?=htmlspecialchars($review['name'], ENT_QUOTES)?></h3>
    <div>
        <span class="rating"><?=str_repeat('&#9733;', $review['rating'])?></span>
        <span class="date"><?=time_elapsed_string($review['submit_date'])?></span>
    </div>
    <p class="content"><?=htmlspecialchars($review['content'], ENT_QUOTES)?></p>
</div>
<?php endforeach ?>
```

Comment: You were very clear. Thanks a lot!

Comment: @LSnake No Worries, if this answer helped please make sure to click the green checkmark next to the answer so Stack Overflow marks this answer as accepted.

Comment: just one thing ... how do i accept reviews? do i have to create a panel where i can accept them?

Comment: You can or if it's just for testing you could use something like phpmyadmin to select ones with status awaiting and manually change them to accepted

Comment: But it would be better for you to create a seperate page for admin panel

Comment: I don't know how to connect this to the panel

Comment: Create a seperate page

Comment: That connects to same db

Comment: sorry, i know you've done too much already but i can't connect the panel, can you give me a guide? can i write to you? :(
I should do the panel where I can accept and reject these requests, but unfortunately I can't get the reviews to go into the panel, it's a mess

Comment: What is the sql code on the panel? It should be `SELECT * FROM reviews WHERE status = "awaiting"`

Comment: i'm quite new to php, i don't know how to connect everything, it's complicated for me, could you help me?

Comment: Sure email rizraak@hotmail.com